# Ljung-Box Statistic

Tags: time-series

Suppose I fit an AR(2) model to a dataset and get the diagnostics. If the Ljung-Box Statistic is significant for all lags for a time series model what is the interpretation of that? Does that mean that the model is not a good fit? Other than this, the ACF of the residuals indicate that they are stationary and normal.

Comment: It is the case (no white noise/iid). Details [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ljung%E2%80%93Box_test). How did you use `ACF` to decide that it is normal?

Answer (score 1):

Are you testing the residuals of the AR(2)? In that case, H0 of the Ljung-Box test is independence, and independence of the residuals is assumed when you fit an AR(p), so that is a good thing. If the Box.test is rejected, your residuals are serially correlated and the order of your model might be wrong, and you should try a different lag length.